# failing to locate controls from code behind.

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, findcontrol

I'm having a problem to get controls/ controls id that I have created manually from code behind. after doing research I found if I create the table and its all component including any controls in Page_Init()  method, when rendering after postback the text value of textbox control should be available to the page. i tried to locate the textbox control using FindControl() method. when debugging it only reach to the line where I tried to locate the control using FindControl() and then throw an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  bellow is the Page_Init() method

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table tb = new Table();
        tb.ID = "Table1";
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
        Button btn = new Button();

        cell1.Text = "Name: ";

        txtbx.ID = "table1_text_input";
        txtbx.ValidationGroup = "rosy";

        cell2.Controls.Add(txtbx);
        btn.Text = "Get the input";
        btn.ValidationGroup = "rosy";
        btn.Click += getBoxinput_Click;
        cell3.Controls.Add(btn);

        // adding cells to row1
        row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
        row1.Cells.Add(cell3);

        // adding row to table1
        tb.Rows.Add(row1);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

    }
```

below is the button click event that supposes to display the control id and its text. I'm stuck with this for the last couple of days. any help will be appreciated.

```
protected void getBoxinput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Table t = (Table)Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("Table1");
                TextBox tbox;

                foreach (TableRow tr in t.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
                    {
                        foreach (Control cnt in tc.Controls)
                        {
                            if (cnt.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                            {
                                tbox = (TextBox)cnt;
                                display.Text += "control id: " + tbox.ID + " control input: " + tbox.Text + "<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {

            display.Text += ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but why don't you just put all the controls in the global scope of the class (instead of just creating the instances inside `Page_Init`) so that you can access them in any part of your class. Of course I am assuming that `Page_Init` and `getBoxinput_Click` are in the same class.

**EDIT:**

Here is the example on how to put the variables in the global scope:

```
Table tb; //Declare variables outside any function.

protected void getBoxinput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb = new Table(); //Initialize them inside a function.
}
```

This way you will be able to access `tb` inside any function.

Comment: both method in the same class. but when you say pull all the controls in the global scope how you do that? if it is not too much to ask would you kindly show me some code that demonstrates to pull all controls from a page. sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: I'm always one step behind I guess. sorry after you told me about pulling controls from the global scope I have done some research and found the same thing as you explained here. massive thanks for that. but unfortunately, a new problem arose which is when I'm adding this table to a panel which is already in the .aspx file, not the code behind file, it throws an error. and don't let me add the table to the panel. it throws same error as before " object reference not set to an instance of an object.  panel attribute "runat" already set to "server".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much experience with ASP.NET, and since your error mentions `attribute "runat" already set to "server"` I guess now is something related to ASP.NET in particular rather than C#. My best guess would be changing the value of the "runat" property to something different than "server" and then change it back to "server". Sorry I cant be of more use here.

Comment: that's ok. I think I found the solution by adding a OnInitComplete() method. so the controls are available to the page. but anyway thanks again for helping out.

Comment: Glad that you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly. Here is what I used for the form markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Label ID="display" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```